# grpc client shows Unavailable errors during server scale up

Tags: kubernetes, jvm, grpc, istio, envoyproxy

I have two grpc services that communicate to each other using Istio service mesh and have envoy proxies for all the services.

We have an issue where during the scaling up of server pods due to high load, the client throws a few grpc UNAVAILABLE(mostly)/DEADLINE_EXCEEDED/CANCELLED errors for a while as soon as the new pod is ready.
I don't see any CPU throttling in server pods at all.

What else could be the issue and how can I investigate this?

Answer (score 1):

Without the concrete status message, it's hard to say what could be the cause of the errors mentioned above.

To reduce UNAVAILABLE, one way to ask the RPC to wait-for-ready: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/wait-for-ready.md. This feature is available in all major gRPC languages (some may rename it to fail-fast=false).

DEADLINE_EXCEEDED is caused by the timeout set by your application or Envoy config, you should be able to tune it.

CANCELLED could mean: 1. the server is entering a graceful shutdown state; 2. the server is overloaded and rejecting new connections.